# Can one MySql table use two instances in Google cloud Sql

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, large-data

We are a google cloud sql user.

We are having a table in cloud sql , the size of table is approximately 400 GB.

The maximum size of instance is 500 GB.

The table size will grow up to 2 TB by end of this year [Just an estimation].

We want to create multiple instances to handle this huge table.

Can we allocate more instances for this table?

Please suggest us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave sharding strategies to other answers, I just want to provide an alternative. Google Cloud Platform has some other solutions that might help you scale:

- Datastore is great for denormalised application storage with fast access.

  - BigQuery is great for advanced offline analytics.
  - If you are willing to manage your own database you can run MySQL in GCE with any size disk supported by GCE.